# how to show tooltip on map image load start with imagemapster

Tags: javascript, imagemapster

i know imagemapster can show tooltip in mouse hover, but i hope keep show that in map load start, how to do?

```
var image = $('img');
image.mapster({
fillColor: 'F0AF02',    
fillOpacity : 0.2,  
stroke: true,
strokeWidth: 2,
strokeColor: '09DA22',
mapKey: 'data-key',
mapValue: 'data-pd',
scaleMap:true,
showToolTip:true,
areas:  [{
           key: "a01", 
           toolTip: "tooltip1",
           staticState: true
        },
        { 
           key: "a02",
           toolTip: "tooltip2",
           staticState: true,               
        }]
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you want. Do you want all defined tooltips to appear on the image as soon as it is loaded - i.e. not just when there is a mouseover an area? It would help us if you could put up a working snippet perhaps with just one or two tooltips.

Comment: @AHaworth yes, keep show on loaded